# Angular Material modal not firing ngChanges on chilld component after change @input value

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a parent component with nested child component. Child component displays a picture using an url that parent shares to it.

I want to change this url when the mat-dialog is closed. The problem is that  ngChanges hook isn't firing after closing the modal. But the parent "url" field is changed.

Here is stackblitz example where you can see the method is not firing changes, then the image is not changing.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c226ox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is firing, you are referencing the wrong name.

Write this in the `ngOnChanges`:

```
if (propName === 'url') { // you had 'user' here
        console.log('changed');
        this.pic = this.getPhoto();
      }
```